# APACHE : Permission denied

Tags: raspbian, web-server, apache-httpd

I have made a raspberry pi web server with Apache, PHP, mysql etc...
In the html folder where are all my .html and .php file I created a new directory called images. I put images into it. But when i try to see the directory in a web browser i get a permission denied 403 error.

[image]

Is there any command to authorize this ?
Thank you ;)

Comment: who owns the folder? what are the permissions on the folder and files?

Comment: Hey thank you to help me again ;) Where do I get the permissions infos ?

Comment: ls -la remember that man ls you may also want to read this http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-lpic1-v3-104-5/

Comment: `pi@192:~ $ sudo -la /var/www/html/images
usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user]
usage: sudo -l [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-U user] [-u user]
            [command]
usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p
            prompt] [-u user] [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]
usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p
            prompt] [-u user] file ...`

Comment: `or this pi@192:~ $ ls -l /var/www/html/images
total 0`

Comment: please don't post important details in the comments, edit your question instead. Also please format them to make them readable.

Comment: Do you have any files in the images directory? what does ls -la /var/www/html output? What you have above is wrong.

Comment: Permission denied as you can see : `pi@192:~ $ ls -la /var/www/html/images
ls: impossible d'accéder à /var/www/html/images/..: Permission non accordée
ls: impossible d'accéder à /var/www/html/images/.: Permission non accordée
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?              ? .
d????????? ? ? ? ?              ? ..`

Comment: and what about ls -la /var/www/html

Comment: authorized for /var/www/html : `total 32
drwxr-xr-x 3 pi       root     4096 nov.  29 17:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 pi       root     4096 nov.  29 17:09 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi       pi        370 nov.  29 17:46 functions.php
drw-r-Sr-- 2 www-data www-data 4096 nov.  29 17:51 images
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi       pi       3484 nov.  29 17:39 index.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi       pi        493 nov.  29 19:02 install_images.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi       pi        236 nov.  29 17:44 mysql.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi       pi       1366 nov.  29 17:46 rate.php`

Comment: Also please edit your question to include the contents of the comments and to format it properly.

Comment: FYI, further questions about Apache, MySQL and PHP should be asked on our sister site stackoverflow.com, as they are off topic here. These are basic Linux questions and the solution is not specific to the Pi. I would have migrated them, but they were poor quality (lacking important info and poorly formatted). Also, there is no need to add thanks to your question, accepting answers and upvoting are the proper way to express your thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once again the problem is ownership and permissions. To fix the problem do the following:

`sudo chown pi:pi /var/www/html/images`

and

```
sudo chmod 755 /var/www/html/images
```

also from the above it does not appear that you have any files in the images directory. You will need to make sure that the ownership and permissions are correct on them as well.

Comment: Is there a command to enable all the images of the directory with only one command ?

Comment: @Omid You need two commands one to change the ownership and one to adjust the permissions - check the man page for the recursive option for the chown and chmod commands man chmod and man chown.